# AdventOfCode Day 1 : find X element matching a criteria in haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, community-challenge

This problem is from https://adventofcode.com/2020/ day 1.

I need to find the N entries of `inputs` that sum to 2020 and then multiply those N numbers together.

```
inputs = [1721, 979, 366, 299, 675, 1456]
```

I have 2 cases `N = 2` and `N = 3`

I have done this with list comprehension

N = 2 :

```
main = print $ head [ i * j |
                      i <- inputs ,
                      j <- inputs ,
                      i+j == 2020]
```

N = 3 :

```
main = print $ head [ i * j * k  |
                      i <- inputs ,
                      j <- inputs ,
                      k <- inputs ,
                      i+j+k == 2020]
```

But it scales badly, if y need `N = 100` that's a lot of `<-`.

So I have done this :

```
solution n =  foldl1 (*) $ head [ x | x <- sequence $ replicate n inputs , (foldl1 (+) x == 2020 )]

main = print $ solution 3
```

I wonder if there is a more idiomatic way to do this and if there is a way of using list comprehension with N variables ?

**Note** : I know that with these solutions, the same entries can be used multiple times, and I am ok with it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome :) Does the title match the standard better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the code certainly works, I wouldn't necessarily call it idiomatic. Haskell's safety and robustness stems from its types, and the type signatures are completely missing. Sure, it works fine. However, all integers are [`Integer` by default](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#verbatim-49), a type that has some nice properties (arbitrary large numbers) and some drawbacks (sub par performance compared to `Int`).

However, to introduce type signatures, we need a function. The third variant introduces a fine candidate: `solution`.

```
solution :: Int -> Int
solution n =  foldl1 (*) $ head [ x | x <- sequence $ replicate n inputs , (foldl1 (+) x == 2020 )]
```

Now that we have a safe foundation and get type errors if we do anything unexpected, let's have a look at the code and the used functions. `foldl1 (*)` is `product` and `foldl1 (+)` is `sum`, although both alternatives act slightly different on an empty list.. Yes, both functions will use `foldr` internally, but that is fine. If we are going for strictness, then we want to use `foldl1'` instead, but that's not necessary with numbers from my experience. Also, `sequence . replicate` is `replicateM` (from `Control.Monad`), and the parentheses around `fold1 (+) x == 2020` aren't necessary. Note that [`hlint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) will report those changes, too.

So without changing the original algorithm, we end up at

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

inputs :: [Int]
inputs = [ ... ]

solution :: Int -> Int
solution n =  product $ head [ xs | xs <- replicateM n inputs
                                  , sum xs == 2020]

main :: IO ()
main = print $ solution 3
```

Note that we changed `x` to `xs`, as we're not dealing with a single element, but instead with lists. This new variant ticks all the boxes:

- it has **explicit** types on its top-level structures ✔
- it uses named variants of `fold`s (`product` for `foldl (*) 1`, `sum` for `foldl (+) 0`) ✔
- it uses typical naming (`xs` for lists) ✔
- it splits functionality into reasonable parts (`main` and `solution`) ✔

However, there's nothing wrong with your old variant, as it was semantically equivalent (except for empty intermediate lists). If I was to solve AoC, I would have used a similar script-style Haskell format, except for `solution`'s type; I'd use `[Int] -> Int` or even `[Int] -> Maybe Int` instead to interact with `map read . lines <$> readFile "inputs"`. But that's personal preference.

And last but not least: Your choice to use the list monad to easily check all \$n\$ combinations was really nice!

Answer (score 1):

### The library gives you all idioms you need

```hs
import Data.List
main=print.product.head.
     filter((2020==).sum).subsequences$
     [1721,979,366,299,675,1456]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcSxDsIgEADQ3a9wcKgJuRS0EAY2R//AdMD2TIlAkTu@H9M3vM3TF2PsPaSyVz4/PHt4BuJT8iG7UkNmKHVf28KwoV/hEyJjHQY1qtG5K1BLR2/CX8O8IF1e0igprLHiprVQ1gptJiHvk557/wM)

Comment: I want only sub-sequences of size N, so using `subsequences` and filter on the size seams a little overkill to me. But I didn't know this one, Thanks !